# None value in a return function

Tags: python, function, return

I had to write a function in Python that returns the highest number of three integer numbers (as arguments), it seemed to easy to me, but proving this in Spyder and VSC, the output is None. I don't understand the reason because the input are three integer numbers.

```
def max_tres_num(a,b,c):
    if a>=b and a>=c:
        return a
    if b>=a and b>=c:
        return b
    if c>=a and c<=b:
        return c
    
print(max_tres_num(1, 2, 3))
> None
```

I tried this code, otherwise I can't discover the reason of the None value or an another way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `c` is the biggest, and in which cases are you returning `c`?

Comment: why `c<=b` instead of `>=`?

Comment: What's a 'return function'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. It looks like `c<=b` is a typo of `c>=b`, so I'm voting to close the question. In the future, following the tips in *[mre]* should help catch simple mistakes like this.

Comment: @Sören I think they mean "function return"

Comment: FWIW, this whole function is redundant. You can just do `max(a, b, c)`. But I assume it's homework and you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error while writing the program where in last condition you put '<' sign rather than '>' sign.

```
def max_tres_num(a,b,c):
    if a>=b and a>=c: 
        return a 
    if b>=a and b>=c: 
        return b 
    if c>=a and c>=b: 
        return c

print(max_tres_num(1, 2, 3))
```

This should work now